# Text disappears in multilingual document with lualatex and polyglossia

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, hebrew

I am attempting to compile the following using `lualatex`

```
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
ש \textenglish{s} מ
\end{document}
```

But only the 'ש' and the 's' are showing. I have synthesized this document from a LyX output. TeX version is 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3. 
 I am using an ubuntu system (xubuntu) and have been trying to get LyX to work with Hebrew for a while. And I am not even a LaTeX beginner, but this looks to me like it should work. So I worry that I might have messed some things up while working on some of the errors on the way to compilation.

Is this code valid?

If not (and this is a bonus question since I can and will make the changes after every LyX output if necessary) why did LyX give me that output?

If it is valid, then how would I be able to compile it?

**edit: Ah yes, thees thing do have log files, they are very long though, here is the interesting part (I think)**

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-hebrew.ldf

Package polyglossia Warning: Hebrew is not supported with LuaTeX.

(polyglossia)                I will proceed with the compilation, but

(polyglossia)                the output is not guaranteed to be correct

(polyglossia)                and may look very wrong. on input line 6.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luabidi.sty

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luabidi/luabidi-footnotes.def))

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/hebrewcal.sty

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/cal-util.def))

Language nohyphenation not found in language.dat.lua

Language hebrew not found in language.dat.lua

Language hebrew not found in language.dat.lua

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/babel-hebrewalph.def))

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):

```
[english,hebrew].
```

(./algebra1.aux

Language hebrew not found in language.dat.lua)

Language hebrew not found in language.dat.lua [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts
/map/pdfte

x/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./algebra1.aux

Language hebrew not found in language.dat.lua))

391 words of node memory still in use:

3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 4 attribute, 50 glue_spec, 4 attribute_lis

t, 1 write nodes

avail lists: 1:1,2:37,3:7,4:1,5:26,6:5,7:13,8:1,9:6

Comment: Your document works for me with all three characters showing. Are there any errors/warnings in the log file? Which TeX distribution do you use?

Comment: I don't have your font but with Arial + xelatex it works. With luatex I get an error. Show your log-file.

Comment: The interesting part is not in the part you are showing. Show the complete log-file. But generally I would say that you should try xelatex instead, I don't think that polyglossia supported hebrew with lualatex in 2017 (and even in TL2019 there is still an error).

Comment: I think LuaLatex and polyglossia don't work quite well with Hebrew. There's a known bug https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/389. Your MWE works fine with XeLaTeX does it not?

Comment: The log file is too long for me to post... but xelatex seems to work, and I have no particular understanding of the difference between them to have any reason to insist on luatex. Thank you very much!